# Cosa sono questi "coralli"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sarto della stradalunga*, di Giuseppe Bonaviri, ho letto:

> Vidi spuntare sorridente mia madre dalla nostra scala annerita e vecchia e avvicinarsi a me con lo scialle di seta che faceva morbide le mani solo a toccarlo e con la veste d'un grigio ulivo che luceva di merletti purissimi e di **coralli** nerastri.

Si tratta di una ragazza contadina che riceve dalle mani di sua madre la prima veste lunga.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa sono questi "coralli" menzionati in questo passaggio? Nessuna delle accezioni di "corallo" che ho trovato nei dizionari mi sembra adatta al contesto del testo.

Comment: Potrebbe trattarsi di decorazioni di pietre dure lucide cucite sul vestito appunto, come decorazione. So che esiste il corallo nero, ma potrebbe trattarsi anche di altri materiali (onice? vetro?)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Avevo già pensato a questo, ma non mi sembra che sia il caso perché si tratta di gente molto umile e povera.

Comment: Potrebbero essere decorazioni in materiali meno pregiati che imitano la forma dei coralli, oppure ricami che replicano dei coralli. Immagino che non ci siano elementi in più, vero?

Comment: No, @Benedetta, purtroppo non c'è niente di più che possa aiutare a capire di cosa si tratta.

Comment: Allora, @Charo, non so se riusciamo a dare una risposta certa. Credo sia possibile solo fare ipotesi.